# nginx configuration for multiple subdirectories containing zf2/php files doesn't work

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, zend-framework

My root structure looks like this

/root/
/root/projectA/...
/root/projectB/...
/root/projectC/...

Before I configured each of my subdirectories with one extra location block in my nginx file. These location "blocks" looked like this:

```
server {
listen   80;
listen   [::]:80;

root /usr/share/root/projectA/public/;
index index.php index.html index.cgi;

server_name www.test.de;

location / {        
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;      
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;       
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

This way my ZF2 application residing in /root/projectA worked as expected. But as the number of subprojects grow, I wanted to use an generic regex solution so I don't have to write the same block over and over again for each subdirectory.

So this was my approach to make those projects available under a subdomain vendor.test.de with each project available under vendor.test.de/projectA/...:

```
server {
listen   80;
listen   [::]:80;

root /usr/share/root/;
index index.php index.html index.cgi;

server_name vendor.test.de;

rewrite_log on;
error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;

location ~ ^/(.+)/ {
    root /usr/share/root/$1/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $1/public/index.php?$args; 

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;       
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }   
}
```

}

But all I get is a 404 and it's just not working.
I debugged the log files a bit, and it seems to behave strange with trying to get /usr/share/root/index.php instead of /usr/share/root/projectA/public/index.php even though he found the right location first...

Any ideas on this?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @Evils, the question itself helped me configure nginx to use index.php as default in subdirectories!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `location` you need to use `alias` instead of `root`.

```
    alias /usr/share/root/$1/public/;
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I still get path errors as nginx is searching on /usr/share/rootprojectA and missing the slash in between.

Comment: You're also missing a `/` in your `try_files`, i.e. `/$1/public/index.php`